# fread from binary returns the same regardless of flags

Tags: c

First I have this:

```
int main (void)
{
   int m = 10;
   double x[3] = {1.5, -3.5, 3.25};

   int n1, n2; FILE *izTok;
   izTok = fopen ("podaci.bin", "wb");

   n1 = fwrite (&m, sizeof(m), 1, izTok);
   n2 = fwrite (x, sizeof(x[0]), 3, izTok);
   fclose(izTok);

   return 0;
}
```

And after that I try to read from it with

```
   FILE *stream;
   stream = fopen("podaci.bin", "r");

   n1 = fread(&n, sizeof(n), 1, stream);
   n2 = fread(arr, sizeof(arr[0]), 3, stream);

   printf("%d %f %f %f", n, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

And regardless of whether I put

```
 stream = fopen("podaci.bin", "r");
```

or

```
 stream = fopen("podaci.bin", "rb");
```

the output is the same

```
 10 1.500000 -3.500000 3.250000
```

Whats the point of the flags if it does the same thing both times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On all POSIX systems, the `b` flag is ignored and has no meaning. From `man 3 fopen` on a Linux system:

> The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last 
>   character  or as a character between the characters in any of the
>   two-character strings described above.  This is strictly for
>   compatibility with    C89  and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on
>   all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.  (Other systems
>   may treat text files and  binary    files  differently, and adding the
>   'b' may be a good idea if you do I/O    to a binary file and expect
>   that your program may be ported to non-UNIX    environments.)

On Windows, `b` means that the data is read unaltered. Otherwise, Text mode is engaged, which is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28VS.71%29.aspx). Among others, line endings are transformed and CTRL+Z is interpreted as end-of-file.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between text and binary depends on your system. Many of the *nixes make a point that on those systems, there is no difference between them. Windows will, in text mode, convert between "\n" and "\r\n" (adding a byte when writing and subtracting when reading).  If you don't happen to have those bytes in your binary data, then you won't notice a difference there either.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the flags is that some Operating Systems treat text and binary streams differently. Yours may not. But it still may: if the double values as binary values contain a byte with value '\r' you may be surprised to find that the numbers you read depend on whether you used "r" or "rb" to open the file.